# SQLite run() callback returns empty object

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

```js
db.run(`UPDATE moneyset SET answer = NULL WHERE userID = '${user.id}'`, (err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(this)
   console.log(`Template literal ${this}`);
});
```

According to the tutorial on https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/update the results I should expect is at least something in `this` object but what I receive is empty object.

console log:

```
> {}
> Template literal [object Object]
```

The results of the `.run()` function can be seen in database so object should not be empty.

Comment: If it is important `.run()` method is nested in `.get()` callback which is bad design i am trying to resolve. Context hastebin: https://hastebin.com/ozevupuqit.js

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` is telling you that `this` is an object. Don't you want to interrogate the `changes` property of that object, à la this line from the tutorial?

```
console.log(`Row(s) updated: ${this.changes}`);
```

Comment: It is empty, no `changes` property even if there are changed rows. But as far I know it should never be empty, it should have `changes = null/undefined` and `lastid = null` properties if no rows have been affected.

Comment: From a little research, the problem is using "this" in the "arrow function" as per [the answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable). And since the example in the tutorial does not use an arrow function, try changing that and see what happens.

Comment: I had this problem.  I was calling db.run() inside an anonymous function.  this didn't exist when the function was anonymous.  I named the anonymous function and it worked